# How can I use the same Instance of an inherited DbContext across the inheritance tree in Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I have a lovely problem in my solution...

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

This is due to the fact that the `UserManager` implementation and, basically, the rest of the code seem to be using different instances of the `DbContext`.

The issue that I have is that the `UserManager` uses a lower level version of the `DbContext` in the inheritance tree (there's about 4 levels of inherited `DbContext` - it's a huge amount of legacy code so changing it isn't an option for me right now).

Here's the `UserManager`...

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<User, int>
{
    private readonly BaseDbContext db;

    public MyUserManager(BaseDbContext dbContext) 
        : base(new UserStore<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>(dbContext))
    {
        db = dbContext;
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("My");

        UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, int>(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
        UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, int>(provider.Create("MyTokenProvider"));
    }
}
```

Everything else uses a class called `MainDbContext`, which inherits from `AnotherDbContext` and then `BaseDbContext`. `AnotherDbContext` isn't used anywhere that matters, so my Ninject is set up as follows...

```
private static IKernel RegisterDatabase(this IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<BaseDbContext>().To<MainDbContext>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<MainDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    return kernel;
}
```

(I use fluent methods for all my IoC setup so this method is called in the main setup).

I thought this would do what I want (use the MainDbContext instance resolution across the board) but it doesn't - It seems I get 1 instance for the `UserManager` and 1 for everything else. It resolves fine (I get the right TYPES) but the instance being different is a dealbreaker.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this I rewrote the `RegisterDatabase` method as follows...

```
private static IKernel RegisterDatabase(this IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<BaseDbContext, OtherDbContext, MainDbContext>()
        .To<MainDbContext>().InRequestScope();
    return kernel;
}
```

This returns the same instance for all types.